# Extract pdf information from papers into org

Tags: org-mode, pdf

I like to use org to take notes on PDFs.  I find Zotero a bit "scattered" and too linked to the papers themselves rather than just being notes.

However, manually extracting information from PDFs can be a pain. Is there a way to pull metadata out of a pdf from a URL and insert it into org-mode?

The metadata I want is the title, authors and institution, and a citation probably.

## Progress so far

- Tried papis cli, was put off by the "backend" concept for different paper sources
- Considered bibtex - but feels like it takes a bit of setting up and I'm not heavy weight yet
- This answer mentioned cb2bib that could be wrapped to do what I want - however it needs to be build from source.
- I'm looking into zotero-cli to see if it'll do what I want.

Comment: What metadata are you looking for? Isn't it enough to store the URL as a link in the Org mode file?

Comment: I added this information. I guess most of it would be in a citation to the pdf. The title is useful for search against and remember when talking to other people. People in academia are weird about citations, sometimes I am lazy and quote one author and feel guilty.

Comment: org-ref https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref provides a lot of tools for working with pdf metadata, particularly for academic writing via bibtex etc.

Comment: Interesting though bibtex looks complicated :/. If I could just circumvent the citation manager and get a citation that would be great.

Comment: Nowadays, Org mode comes with [org-cite](https://orgmode.org/manual/Citation-handling.html) which might or might not help (I have not used it). I remembered `org-ref` but I see that @Tyler has already recommended  it. I'm not sure what you mean by "getting a citation": just unformatted text, containing the metadata you mentioned? IME, "citations" are entries in a database, so they need to conform to the database schema.

Comment: The usual tools for reference management in Emacs include org-ref, Zotero (which can be configured to create a local bibtex database), and https://github.com/tmalsburg/helm-bibtex. It sounds like you want something more lightweight and customized to your workflow. I suspect this may end up being more work than what it would take to use one of the existing tools, so it might be worth taking a look. I think `ivy-bibtex`, which is part of `helm-bibtex`, is likely the simplest option.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I was pretty keen to get his set up so spent a while fiddling.

## Zotero

As Tyler says I think Zotero with `helm-bibtex` is the way to go, and this still seems pretty lightweight. There's a little bit of magic need to get Zotero to create a bibtex file and keep it up-to-date, for this you can use [zotero better bibtex](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/%5D).

- Install Zotero
- Download [better bibtex for zotero](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/installation/). Firefox will try to open the xpi extension itself - so right click and the download link and click "save as".
- Go to `Tools > Addons` and add add the better bibtex extension that you downloaded
- Restart zotero
- Go to your library. Right click on a collection, click export, setting the exporter to better bibtex and click "keep uptodate". Export to ~/references.bib
- Install `helm-bibtex`
- Set the bibliography path `(setq bibtex-completion-bibliography '("~/library.bib")`
- `helm-bibtex` can then open references from your bibliography. If you press tab in helm you can also insert citations
- To insert a citation you can use

```
(defun my-helm-bibtex-cite ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((helm-source-bibtex (copy-alist helm-source-bibtex)))
    (helm-add-action-to-source "Reference 4" 'helm-bibtex-insert-reference helm-source-bibtex 0)
    (helm-bibtex)))
```

### Including URLs

This works well enough... unless you want urls. The code to creating cites is all rather hard coded and "monkey patch'y". A similar approach could be used for custom interfaces

Zotero does not include urls by default - because apparently bibtex clients don't support urls. So you need to [enable an option](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/installation/preferences/export/) in better bibtex in zotero

```
(defun my-helm-bibtex-cite-with-url ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((helm-source-bibtex (copy-alist helm-source-bibtex)))
    (helm-add-action-to-source "Reference" 'my-helm-bibtex-insert-reference-and-url helm-source-bibtex 0)
    (helm-bibtex)))

;; hack won't work for multiple entries
(helm-bibtex-helmify-action my-bibtex-completion-insert-reference-and-url my-helm-bibtex-insert-reference-and-url)
(defun my-bibtex-completion-insert-reference-and-url (keys)
  "Insert references for entries in KEYS."
  (let* ((refs (--map
                (s-word-wrap fill-column
                             (concat "\n- " (bibtex-completion-apa-format-reference it)))
                keys)))
    (insert
     (s-format
             "${url} ${doi}"
             'bibtex-completion-apa-get-value
             (bibtex-completion-get-entry (car keys)))
     "\n" (s-join "\n" refs) "\n")))
```

### User experience

Copying and pasting a URL is wonderfully simple. Things aren't so simple with zotero... though it's not too bad.

- You can add zotero connect to your toolbar in firefox (no shortcut unfortunately) by right-clicking.
- You still need to look up added entry once you've added it. But the bibtex file seems to be updated pretty instantly and you often will only need to type a few characters.

## Not using zotero

So before this I also did it in a command line way... given the time now I think it was quicker to do than use zotero. But the zotero solution has a few benefits (zotero is kept up-to-date, files are downloaded, zotero has quite a nice interfaces for some things, zotero allows annotation, etc etc).

This script (called `cite-fetch`) will fetch citations from arxiv (and only arxiv). There is also a way of getting citations in bibtex format from crossref - but arxiv citations appeared to be missing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import io
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

import requests

HERE = Path(__file__).parent
EXPORT = HERE / "simple.bibtexconv"


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("url")
parser.add_argument(
    "-f",
    "--format",
    type=str,
    help="What format to output in. (Defaults to bibtex)",
    choices=("simple", "bibtex"),
    default="bibtex",
)
args = parser.parse_args()

parts = urlparse(args.url)

if parts.path.startswith("/pdf/"):
    new_path = Path("/bibtex") / Path(parts.path).relative_to(Path("/pdf"))
elif parts.path.startswith("/abs/"):
    new_path = Path("/bibtex") / Path(parts.path).relative_to(Path("/abs"))
else:
    raise ValueError(args.url)

new_parts = parts._replace(path=str(new_path))
new_path = urlunparse(new_parts)
response = requests.get(new_path)
content = response.text

if args.format == "bibtex":
    print(content)
elif args.format == "simple":
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        temp_dir = Path(temp_dir)
        bib_file = temp_dir / "bib.bib"
        with open(bib_file, "w") as stream:
            stream.write(response.text)

        with open(EXPORT) as stream:
            template = stream.read()

        p = subprocess.Popen(
            ["bibtexconv", bib_file], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE
        )
        output, _ = p.communicate(template.encode("utf-8"))
        print(args.url)
        print(output.decode("utf8"))
```

You can then use this after copying a url from the clipboard to insert a citation.

```
(defun my-insert-cite (url)
  (interactive (list (shell-command-to-string "pbpaste || xclip -o")))
  (insert (shell-command-to-string (format "cite-fetch -f simple %s" url))))
```

## Alternatives to helm-bibtex

It looks like there are a few alternatives to helm-bibtex that could similarly read a citation generate by better bibtex in zotero.

org-citar in one choice - which can also read CSL citation libraries - which seems like it might be a more common standard.

Comment: The `helm-bibtex` code to parse bibtex all seems a little ad hoc and regexpy. So do complex things I think either using a [python library](https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/en/main/) or converting to [bibjson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268294/convert-existing-bibtex-to-bibjson) might be the way to go.